# Elapsed Time for Open a Microsoft Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, office-interop

it's possible to calculate the elapsed time from the "opening" of a word document( operation normally made by double click on the document) until the effective view of the document in Word?

I thinked that the start of my timespan may be the process.Start of the application.
But how can i know when the document is effectively opened in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Word is not _interactive_ until it has finished to open the document so you can use it to check when it has finished (send a message with **SendMessageTimeout**). System.Diagnostic.Process has a **Responding** property to check this. It'll be true when view will be available. It's not a reliable check (especially because you can't hope timing will be accurate) but it's a start point. If you can't add a startup **macro** in the document to notify your application you may also consider to check for a **child window of the proper class**. Use WinSpy then FindWindow to find it in code.

Comment: Maybe i've solved my problem.
 In Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application there is en event called DocumentOpen that raised when the document is ready to be used:
i hooked this event and i took the DateTime.Now of the operation.
Any suggestions/observations?

Comment: Such measurements are not in general meaningful, there's a huge difference between the cold and the hot start time.  Your user typically sees a cold start, you'll measure a hot start.

Answer (score 1):

Interop is synchronous so you should be able to do this :

```
string path = "";
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excel.Workbooks.Open(path, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
Console.ReadKey();
```